# DNS is resolving fine but can't access the server (unless changing /etc/hosts)

Tags: domain-name-system, vps

I have a VPS server with a public IP, I added some A entries in my name server like svn.example.com -> 1.1.1.1

Also I added some entries in my workstation `/etc/hosts` file in order to work with the domains meanwhile the DNSs were refreshed.

It's been around 3 days from this and I configures everything in my server (using the `hosts` file), the DNSs are ready and I removed the entries but for my surprise I can access the servers nor anything in my domain or sub-domains (even a ping doesn't work).

I've triple checked and the DNSs are OK. I don't know too much about DNSs . Any help would be appreciated.

The IP address of my VPS is `74.63.223.43`

I have these domain names, all pointing to the same IP (using A entries)

> hartoingenio.com
>   www.hartoingenio.com
>   svn.hartoingenio.com

Comment: Can you post the fqdn? It should be quick to diagnose that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your DNS is pointing to 76.63.223.43 while your IP is 74.63.223.43.

```
tsavo:~ mcd$ host hartoingenio.com 8.8.8.8
Using domain server:
Name: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
Aliases: 

hartoingenio.com has address 76.63.223.43
hartoingenio.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx3.googlemail.com.
hartoingenio.com mail is handled by 0 aspmx.l.google.com.
hartoingenio.com mail is handled by 5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
hartoingenio.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx5.googlemail.com.
hartoingenio.com mail is handled by 5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
hartoingenio.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx4.googlemail.com.
hartoingenio.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx2.googlemail.com.
tsavo:~ mcd$ host www.hartoingenio.com 8.8.8.8
Using domain server:
Name: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
Aliases: 

www.hartoingenio.com has address 76.63.223.43
tsavo:~ mcd$ host svn.hartoingenio.com 8.8.8.8
Using domain server:
Name: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
Aliases: 

svn.hartoingenio.com has address 76.63.223.43
```

Comment: OK now I feel embarrased